# How to add algolia image to to the bottom of autocomplete results

Tags: html, css, autocomplete, algolia

I am using [algolia](https://www.algolia.com/) autocomplete service and would like to add an image 
to the bottom of the autocomplete results like it is shown in their examples here:

[image]

This is how my autocomplete.js looks like:

```
autocomplete('#search-input', {}, [
    {
      source: autocomplete.sources.hits(players, { hitsPerPage: 5 }),
      displayKey: 'first_name',
      templates: {
        header: '<div class="aa-suggestions-category">Players</div>',
        suggestion: function(suggestion) {
          return '<span>'
                + '<a href="/player/' + suggestion.id + '">'
                +   '<div class="media">'
                +     '<div class="media-left">'
                +       '<img class="media-object" src="/imagecache/small/' + suggestion.image_filename + '">'
                +     '</div>'
                +     '<div class="media-body">'
                +       '<p>' + suggestion._highlightResult.first_name.value + " " + suggestion._highlightResult.last_name.value + '<small> ' + old + ' years</small>' + '</p>'
                +       '<small> ' + suggestion.nationality + ' '+ suggestion.position + '</small>'
                +     '</div>'
                +   '</div>'
                + '</a>'
                +'</span>';
        }
      }
    },
    {
      source: autocomplete.sources.hits(videos, { hitsPerPage: 5 }),
      displayKey: 'title',
      templates: {
        header: '<div class="aa-suggestions-category">Videos</div>',
        suggestion: function(suggestion) {
          timeAgo();
          return '<span>'
                +  '<a href="/player/video/' + suggestion.uid + '">'
                +    '<div class="media">'
                +      '<div class="media-left">'
                +        '<img class="media-object" src="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/videos.football-talents.com/' + suggestion.video_id + '_1.jpg">'
                +      '</div>'
                +      '<div class="media-body">'
                +        '<p>' + suggestion._highlightResult.title.value + ' <small class="timeago" title="' + suggestion.created_at + '">' + suggestion.created_at + '</small>' + '</p>'
                +        '<small> ' + suggestion._highlightResult.player_name.value + " " + suggestion._highlightResult.player_surname.value + '</small>'
                +      '</div>'
                +    '</div>'
                +  '</a>'
                +'</span>';
        }
      }
    }
]).on('autocomplete:updated', function(event, suggestion, dataset) {
  var timeagoTimeout;
  clearTimeout(timeagoTimeout);
  timeAgo();
  timeagoTimeout = setTimeout(timeAgo, 60000);
});
```

Where should I add an image so that it is at the bottom of the result, like it is on the image I have posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `footer` template option like described [here](https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js#options).

```
$('#search-input').autocomplete({
    templates: {
      footer: '<div class="branding">Powered by <img src="https://www.algolia.com/assets/algolia128x40.png" /></div>'
    }
  }, [
    /// here your sources
  ]
);
```